# How to fill null cells in pandas data frame with a list of numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, geopandas

I have a list of numbers and i want to fill those numbers in the cells of pandas data frame.
For instance,

```
Lst=[216516.61000000002,
 214771.62000000002,
 213026.63000000003,
 211281.64000000004,
 209536.65000000005,
 207791.66000000006,
 206046.67000000007,
 204301.68000000008,
 202556.6900000001]
```

and [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YywAF.png)

I want to fill each numbers from the list Lst individually to the index number #131 of the data frame such as 216516.61000000002 needs to fill in the column name "2001" and index #131, 214771.62000000002 to Column name "2002" and index #131 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You can access the row by using `loc` and reuse `loc` to get only a part of this row, then replace this row by a `Series` with the right `data` and `index` :

```
df.loc[0].loc[2001:] = pd.Series(data=Lst, index=[2001,...])
```